# Customize database result [Symfony 4]

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, repository, symfony4

I have like a search Form
I want for example search by Categorie, diplome, salaire,

Categorie, diplome works good
but my probleme is in salaire ( type float), when the form salaire null i want the Query return all Result of Categorie, diplome and ignore salaire

and when form salaire not null, i want the query return result of categorie+diplome+salaire list

this the controller

```
$data = $form->getData();
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Candidat::class);
            $candidats = $repository->findListByFilter($data->getCategorie(),$data->getDiplome(),$data->getSalaire());
```

This is the repository

```
     public function findListByFilter($categorie,$diplome,$salaire):array
        {

            return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->andWhere('c.categorie = :categorie')
                ->andWhere('c.diplome = :diplome')
                ->andWhere('c.salaire <= :salaire')
                ->setParameter('categorie', $categorie)
                ->setParameter('diplome', $diplome)
                ->setParameter('salaire', $salaire)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
                ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `IFs` to accomplish this kind of request:

```
public function findListByFilter(string $categorie, string $diplome, ?float $salaire = null): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.categorie = :categorie')
        ->andWhere('c.diplome = :diplome')
        ->setParameters([
            'categorie' => $categorie,
            'diplome' => $diplome
        ]);

    if($salaire) {
        $qb->andWhere('c.salaire <= :salaire')->setParameter('salaire', $salaire);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery->getResult();
}
```

You are using Symfony 4 so I recommend you to start using type-hint for your variables.